# Prevent parent deletion with SQLAlchemy backref

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model for an organization:

```
class Organization(SharedModel):
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
```

and several models that backref `Organization` like this:

```
class OrganizationBusinessLine(db.Model):
     organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organization.id'), nullable=False)
     organization = db.relationship('Organization', foreign_keys=[organization_id],
                               single_parent=True,
                               backref=db.backref('businessLines', uselist=True))

     name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
```

When a `Organization` is deleted, I want all `OrganizationBusinessLine`s that are associated with the organisation to be deleted, and this works just fine:

```
def test_that_children_of_organization_are_deleted(session)
    organization_id = 1
    organization = session.query(Organization).get(organization_id)
    business_line_ids = [instance.id for instance in
                         session.query(OrganizationBusinessLine).filter_by(organization=organization).all()]

    db.session.delete(instance)
    db.session.commit()
    for instance_id in business_line_ids:
        assert session.query(OrganizationBusinessLine).get(instance_id) is None
```

But when I delete a business line, the associated organisation is also deleted:

```
def test_that_parent_is_not_deleted(session):
    business_line = session.query(OrganizationBusinessLine).first()

    business_line_id = business_line.id
    organization_id = business_line.organization_id

    OrganizationBusinessLine.delete(business_line_id)

    assert session.query(OrganizationBusinessLine).get(business_line_id) is None
    assert session.query(Organization).get(organization_id) is not None # Fails
```

I have tried several different `cascade=`-options on the `backref`, but I can't get the "parent" (`Organization`) to not be deleted.

The default `cascade=` options for backrefs are [according to the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#backref-cascade):

> The default behavior of cascade is limited to cascades of the so-called save-update and merge settings.

I would expect these settings to not even delete the "children" objects, but it seems to do.

I'm running the tests on my local SQLite database, if that matters.

Comment: Please post the definition of `OrganizationBusinessLine.delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the relationship for the parent class and refer to the parent foreignkey with an ondelete=`CASCADE`:

```
class Organization(SharedModel):
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    businneslines = relationship(
        'Component',
        backref=backref("organization"),
        cascade="all,delete"
    )

class OrganizationBusinessLine(db.Model):
    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                                db.ForeignKey('organization.id'), 
                                nullable=False)
    organization_id =  Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('organization.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```